# Compile error in phonegap , an error while building?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

[image]

I'm trying to complie an app using phonegap , i keep getting the following error..any idea?

[image]

Comment: You can try to run `$home/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/check_reqs` to see what error log it displays.

Comment: And maybe upgrading to 3.4 and/or switching to cordova instead of phonegap would help to get clearer errror message.

Answer (score 1):

type this on terminal or commant prommpt:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Simple follow this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

It will open one editor. than

```
Edit the path of sdk tools and platform-tools and add Ant path



export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-bundle/sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/android-bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"

export ANT_HOME="$HOME/ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: i think you are work on mac osx os do't add Ant use just simply only    export PATH=${PATH}:"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools":"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools"

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that i was using 64 bit version of ubuntu did this and worked fine. 
Thanks guys

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```